# Question regarding IotHub to eventgrid(device telemetry) to webhook(one endpoint)

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventgrid

Just wanted to understand how the IotHub +EventGrid+WebHook works. When the IoThub receives the device telemetry which triggers the EventGrid which is mapped to one endpoint, does this follow the synchronous workflow? Does the IoThub send 200ok to the device after receiving the telemetry or does it wait for eventgrid to receive 200 ok from the web service endpoint?

Comment: I now see you asked this before, please refrain from asking the same question twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the IoThub send 200ok to the device after receiving the telemetry or does it wait for eventgrid to receive 200 ok from the web service endpoint?

No it doesn't. It would certainly not make it scale if it did. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry):

> Events are sent to the registered endpoint of each subscription immediately. If an endpoint doesn't **acknowledge receipt** of an event, Event Grid retries delivery of the event.

So Event Grid will wait for a receipt acknowledgement, not for the duration of the processing.